# How to make my discord bot play an audio file over another dynamically?

Tags: python, discord

I made a discord bot in Python using **discord.py** that has a command that pops up a sort of "soundbar", users can choose to click one button and then the soundbar will disappear and the bot will play the sound in the voice channel of the user.
But what if I want to copy the *behavior* of the discord soundbar and play sounds over others?
Because of how it is right now there's the little chance that a **user will click a button while the bot is already playing something and it will ignore it**.

I can see that with the basic discord.py and FFmpeg libraries, it seems not possible, are there any stream/thread based media libraries that can help? Since is a command we would only use for fun on my server I don't want to get too over-complicated stuff.

Comment: well the only idea that comes to mind to me is to have a mixer in the background that combines both your audio and fx stream and then passing it over to discord. AFAIK there is no other option.